Absolute positioned image ignoring left and right
I’m trying to place an image in a relative container (which has a width and height) 20px from the top, left and right like this:
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px; width: 200px">
  <img src="x" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px;">
</div>

My image however, as it doesn’t have a width set is just defaulting to its own width and overflowing (the parent have overflow hidden).
Any ideas how to make this work? I may have some other CSS which is causing the issue but I tried to just give a clean example.

Just for you I’ve updated them. Makes almost 0 difference with modern IDEs and prettier.

You are doing just fine.  Need to set image height and width accordingly.
Firstly, the image container should have overflow hidden so that the image will not overlap the container.
Secondly, the image height and width must be according to parent's height and width.  You can set height and width by subtracting the padding from top, right, bottom, and left sides.
Following example could you of use.


.img-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - 40px);
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  object-fit: cover;
}
<div class='img-container'>
  <img class='img' src="https://images.freeimages.com/images/large-previews/355/poppies-2-1334190.jpg" />
</div>




I was hoping to avoid using a calc to set width but it LOLs like the only solution

Do it like that, Its working.


.parent {
    position: relative;
    background-color:#ddd;
    width:200px;           
    height:100px; 
}

#image {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:20px;
    right: 20px;
}
<div class="parent" >
    <img id="image" src="x">
</div>




Not working I’m afraid, the image sets its own size still

Try it like this. It will work
<div style="position: relative; height: 100px; width: 200px; overflow: hidden;">
     <img src="x" style="position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; right: 20px; width: calc(100% - 40px);">
</div>


While the answer may be helpful, you might want to provide additional information explaining why that is the case.
